# Bootstrap4 avoid hiding modal when clicking anywhere outside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I would like to override this default behavior.
Any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From HTML

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

From Jquery

```
$('#your_id_modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

---

PD:  I leave you the complete documentation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-options